# Persistent white dot in Ubuntu Dock since 18.10 update

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

The issue is that white dot stays in Ubuntu dock (Favorites bar) after you moved something:

[image: screenshot]

The second one is I can't remove Kazam, even though it's not running.

Comment: Please don't club more than one issue in a question. Ask about unrelated in a new question. And try to use a descriptive title.

Comment: Are you talking about the white for below system monitor icon?

Answer (score 0):

If the white dot bothers you, you can remove it by restarting GNOME shell.
To do this, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, then type `r`, and finally press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.